# Magento configurable product -> floating/sliding cart

Tags: magento, frontend, cart

we have a pc configurator, actually its not a "configured product" but a product with "custom options".

we want to have a "cartbox" that shows the selected attributes plus price that slides with the movement of the page down untill the user has viewed all options.

any ideas?

i am pretty sure that there is no ready module.

thanx for any help

Comment: Not really a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a theming question for the product page template, but with some frontend programming thrown in for good measure...

You have to know a little bit about Prototype to tackle this 'purely in frontend javascript' but I think it can be done.

I am assuming you have a 'div' that is styled up to be 'position: fixed' so that it always stays to the right of the screen, no matter how you scroll down the page. Then in this div is a table (or more divs) that summarises all of your options. All of those table options are marked up with ids.

In your template code for the custom product options you can have some php code to detect the attribute-set for 'custom pc' and write out some extra front-end javascript. This is then able to listen to the changes to the custom options and update your extra summary information in the fixed position div.

Unless you are really good at Prototype you may want to give yourself 2-3 days to get the code in there, the same again for testing and putting in a modest amount of products.